# How to test oninput event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code that registers event handlers to my refs:

```
componentDidMount() {
   for (const x in this.refs) {
      this.refs[x].oninput = (e) => this.handleInput(e, this.refs[x])
   }
}
```

But I'm having trouble triggering them via my tests.

I've tried triggering events manually doing things like:

```
rendered.find('.myClass')
  .first()
  .simulate('input', { target: { value: '1' } })
```

But these don't seem to hit the event handlers.

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: Enzyme/jest I think (not entirely sure which is the framework here)